# Having trouble with Jumbotron

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a Jumbotron in Bootstrap 3.0. I want my image to take up the first three columns and my text to take up the other nine. However, when I input my code the image and the text cross over each other.

HEre is my code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="col-lg-offset-3">Content Strategist and Designer</h1>

    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
            <img src="img/cover.png">
            </div>

        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
            <p>Hello,</p>
                <p> My name is Bryan Collins and I am a student of the Digital Skills Academeny WebElevate 2.1 programme, where I specialised in the creation of online content.</p>
                <p>Throughout my professional career, I have written and produced various types of multimedia for a variety of Irish online and offline publications.</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn More</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your image contains the `img-responsive` class so that it scales accordingly for the column. Also, if you want to use 3 cols for the image, and 9 cols for the text (as you've described) use the appropriate `col-md-3` and `col-md-9` instead of `col-md-5`

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="col-lg-offset-3">Content Strategist and Designer</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="//placehold.it/800x950" class="img-responsive">
            </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <p>Hello,</p>
                <p> My name is Bryan Collins and I am a student of the Digital Skills Academeny WebElevate 2.1 programme, where I specialised in the creation of online content.</p>
                <p>Throughout my professional career, I have written and produced various types of multimedia for a variety of Irish online and offline publications.</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn More</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/86474

Comment: That worked thanks. There is a large amount of space beside my image. I set the image and text to col-md-6 respectively. The image itself is over 900px in size and is a png. How do I make it bigger?

Comment: Once you use `img-responsive`, the img will scale to its' container.. so if you make the col wider the image will get bigger. Maybe try `col-md-7` image and `col-md-5` for text?

Comment: Is there a way of getting it to scale like the iMac in this link: http://builtwithbootstrap.com/post/13161389590/goncalo-rodrigues-a-nice-portfolio-site-using

Comment: This is what I have so far: wpsite56.webelevate.ie